# updates page shows an error for a mystery module 'standard 8.6.12'

Tags: 8, updating, composer

on the updates page `/admin/reports/updates` under Modules there is a module called **standard 8.6.12** as and it is highlighted with a warning `No available releases found (Warning)`

this module does not appear when running `$ composer outdated`

is there any idea where this module is coming from, if it is in fact needing an update, or if this is just a typo in one of the site's config files somewhere?

this is what I see:
[image]

I have recently updated to Drupal 8.6.12 (using `$ composer update`)

Comment: Is it referring to the profile?

Comment: thx @Kevin I hadn't considered that - that would align with the `web\core\profiles\standard` profile - and looking at the `standard.info.yml` there are some modules and themes that I have removed as part of my install. For ex) I uninstalled the 'bartik' theme and modules like 'history' and 'tour'

Comment: it increments every time that I update Drupal core - so now it is at `standard 8.6.13`. how is this related to core and why is it appearing as a module?

Comment: You removed the standard profile? Like in deleted it? It belongs to Drupal core. Don't touch anything in core.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

going to mark this as answered so I can close it...

I removed a contrib module that we are no longer using and the mystery module "**standard 8.6.12**" no longer appears.

I cannot say for certain which module it was - but I am 99.78% certain it was from a contrib module, not from a core one.